# android: how to make interface between recycler view and adapter clss

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` which has Switch Button on each item and I want to add `switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener` for items. how can I make an interface between adapter class and the recyclerview host activity??

Answer (score 0):

First you will create an interface class

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
    void udpateData(String data);
}
```

The interface will be defined with name and parameters that you want

Second in the activity or fragment having RecycleView, you need implement this interface.

Third, when you call the your adapter please pass this `interface` to your adapter. Each time your Switch Button change status, `interface` will call updateData method to update data

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In your host activity write a method to handle switch button changed, say

```
private void switchButtonChanged()
```

pass the host activity when you create the adapter, for example

`Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity())`

under your **onCheckedChangedListener()** in adapter, fire `hostActivity.switchButtonChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it. interface.

```
public class YourAdapter extends YourAdapterExtends {
private AdapterInteractionListener adapterInteractionListener;
... // your adapter codes
public YourAdapter(AdapterInteractionListener adapterInteractionListener){
this.adapterInteractionListener = adapterInteractionListener;
}

//call where you call switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener method
switch. setOnCheckedChangeListener{
adapterInteractionListener.onSwitched;
}


//here your interaction interface.

    public interface AdapterInteractionListener{
        void onSwitched();
    }
}
```

And your host activity

```
public class YourActivity extends YourExtends impelements YourAdapter.AdapterInteractionListener {
...//your activity codes
@Override
onSwitched{
//here your switch listener triggered here
}

}
```

I hope this helps.